# Doctrine in Symfony: use a single “Author” associative entity related to different entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm developing a custom content management system with Symfony 5 and Doctrine.

I'm trying to implement a relation between the entities `Document` and `Video` (actually there are many more, but for simplicity sake let's say are just two) and the `User` entity.

The relation represent the `User` who wrote the document or recorded the video. So the relation here is called `Author`. Each document or video can have one or more author. Each User can have none or more document or video.

I would like to **use just a single associative `Author` associative entity**, like this:

`entity_id|author_id|entity`

Where:

- `entity_id`: is the id of the document or video
- `author_id`: is the `user_id` who authored the entity
- `entity`: is a constant like `document` or `video` to know to which entity the relation refer to

The problem is that I cannot understand how to build this in Doctrine. Was this a classic `SingleEntity<-->Author<-->Users` relationship I would have build it as a ManyToMany item, but here it's different.

`Author` would probably contain two ManyToOne relations (one with the `User` entity and one with either the `Document` or the `Video` entity) plus the `entity type` field, but I really don't know how to code the "Document`or`Video`" part. I mean:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=??????????, inversedBy="authors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $entity; // Document or Video

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $entityType;
```

How should I manage the first field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if would be better to store it under two differents attributes. If not and mandatory, I think those "objects" should have a common interface or something, so take a look to [doctrine inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping) that should fulfill your needs

Comment: [Single table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to store the entity namespace Ex. `Acme\Entity\Document` in a property and the id in another and to use the entity manager to get the entity.

Edit: Though you won't have the relation, I prefer that way over others because it is reusable and the performance is rather the same. Also if I need to pass it to a JSON response, I just create a normalizer and I am good to go.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $entityNamespace;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $entityId;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getEntity()
{
    return $this->em->getRepository($this->entityNamespace)->find($this->entityId);
}
```